# Camel NMR Testing : where is AbstractComponentTest?

Tags: testing, apache-camel, esb, apache-servicemix

I am trying to create tests for a couple of camel routes that use the servicemix nmr component. [Documentation](http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.8/component_ref/_IDU_NMR.html) says that one needs to extend org.apache.servicemix.camel.nmr.AbstractComponentTest but i can't find it. (added dependency org.apache.servicemix.camel.component)

I have tried looking in the camel-nmr example but it does not include tests.

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**
This was specific to camel 2.8

Comment: I logged a ticket to have the FuseSource documentation improved: http://fusesource.com/issues/browse/ESB-1663

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Apache ServiceMix, and is being tracked in this JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SMX4-944.